# Read MPU6050 over I2C with STM32 nucleo board

Tags: stm32, i2c, imu

I am working with a **NUCLEO-F401RE** board and I want to connect the accelerometer sensor [MPU6050](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Datasheet1.pdf) (on a GY-521 module). The device can be connected to the board over I2C.

I connected the 3.3V of the board to VCC, GND to GND, SDA to PB9 and SCL to PB8.

I also tried to connect pull up resistor (10k) between VCC and SDA and VCC & SCL.

With the code below, I am trying to see if the device is connected however, the code desperately returns `HAL_ERROR` status code 1.

More specifically, this line `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, 10, i2c_timeout)` return the code 1 that corresponds to `HAL_StatusTypeDef` `HAL_ERROR`

I did try with 3 different devices and all behave the same way.

When I try to read `WHO_AM_I_REG` (register 0x75) I am getting 0.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
    #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
    #include "uart.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    #define SMPLRT_DIV_REG 0x19
    #define GYRO_CONFIG_REG 0x1B
    #define ACCEL_CONFIG_REG 0x1C
    #define ACCEL_XOUT_H_REG 0x3B
    #define TEMP_OUT_H_REG 0x41
    #define GYRO_XOUT_H_REG 0x43
    #define PWR_MGMT_1_REG 0x6B
    #define WHO_AM_I_REG 0x75
    
    I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;
    
    void i2c1_init(void);
    void MPU6050_Init(void);
    
    // Setup MPU6050
    #define MPU6050_ADDR (0x68 << 1) // 0xD0
    const uint16_t i2c_timeout = 100;
    
    int main() {
    
        HAL_Init();
    
        i2c1_init();
        uart_init();
    
        MPU6050_Init();
    
        while (1) {
    
        }
    }
    
    void i2c1_init(void) {
        /*
         * PB8 --> I2C1_SCL
         * PB9 --> I2C1_SDA
         */
        GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8 | GPIO_PIN_9;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD; // alternate function - open drain
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_I2C1;
    
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    
    // Remap I2C1 pins
    //__HAL_RCC_AFIO_CLK_ENABLE();
    //__HAL_AFIO_REMAP_I2C1_ENABLE();
    
        // Configure I2C
        __HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();
    
        __HAL_RCC_I2C1_FORCE_RESET();
        HAL_Delay(2);
        __HAL_RCC_I2C1_RELEASE_RESET();
    
        hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
        hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
        hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2; // half-high, half low
        hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
        hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
        hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
        hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
        hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
    
        if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK) {
            printf("Error setting up the I2C !\n");
        }
    }
    
    void MPU6050_Init(void) {
    
        uint8_t check, Data;
        HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, 10,
                i2c_timeout);
        if (status != HAL_OK) {
            printf("Is Ready: %d \n", status);
        }
    
    // check device ID WHO_AM_I
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, WHO_AM_I_REG, 1, &check, 1, 1000);
        if (check == 104) // 0x68 will be returned by the sensor if everything goes well
                {
    // power management register 0X6B we should write all 0's to wake the sensor up
            Data = 0;
            HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, PWR_MGMT_1_REG, 1, &Data, 1,
                    i2c_timeout);
    // Set DATA RATE of 1KHz by writing SMPLRT_DIV register
            Data = 0x07;
            HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, SMPLRT_DIV_REG, 1, &Data, 1,
                    i2c_timeout);
    // Set accelerometer configuration in ACCEL_CONFIG Register
    // XA_ST=0; YA_ST=0; ZA_ST=0; FS_SEL=0 -> +: 2g
            Data = 0x00;
            HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, ACCEL_CONFIG_REG, 1, &Data, 1,
                    i2c_timeout);
    // Set Guroscopic configuration in GYRO_CONFIG Register
    // XG_ST=0; YG_ST=0; ZG_ST=0; FS_SEL=0 -> +/- 250 °/s
            Data = 0x00;
            HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MPU6050_ADDR, GYRO_CONFIG_REG, 1, &Data, 1,
                    i2c_timeout);
    
        }
    }
    
    void SysTick_Handler(void) {
        HAL_IncTick();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where exactly it blocks, and what does it mean HAL status code=1?

Comment: OK. What does HAL error code 1 means then? What do the I2C function return as their value and why are you not using the return value to determine what went wrong? Have you debugged the code on any way, have you looked the bus with an oscilloscope or logic analyzer?

Comment: Yes I did try to debug the sensor using a logic analyzer, I can indeed read the register 0x75 and see the value.
I also explained a bit more the error code 1 in the initial question

Comment: GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH setting, probably is not compatible with I2C. Internal pull-ups usually are not sufficient, for I2C, you do need external ones.

Comment: So did you single step code to see why and where it returns error code 1? If it can read the register value but deviceready indicates an an error, are you sure the chip can handle the protocol used by deviceready to determine if a device is ready or not?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič lowering the frequency does not help, the code doesn't work

Comment: @Justme I am not sure if the device support deviceready but I am sure it support WHO_I_AM register and this one also return 0x00 instead of 0x68 - using a logic analyser I can see the 0x68 when I read the register but for some reason the code doesn't work - I did try a different nucleo board and have the same issue (L476RG)

Comment: I also checked the continuity of my cable and all is correct, the led on the MCU is green

Comment: So single step the code to see where it works or not. If there is 0x68 that is the address, 0x75 would be the register index. If you don't see that, the chip is not present. Does it ACKnowledge the I2C address? When HAL returns error code 1, what is the hi2c.ErrorCode? Please single step through the code already and post logic analyzer traces to see if the chip is even listening. What LED are you now suddenly talking about?

Comment: I added a picture to show that the led on the MPU is turned on - I will single step to see if I can find where the code is returning the error

Comment: @Justme when I do signle step debugging I see that inside the function `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady` the code is doing a tiral for every Trials without success, it then return a HAL_ERROR

Comment: Yes, and the ErrorCode would tell what the error is.

Comment: I just realized you said module. Why do you feed it 3.3V as it has onboard 3.3V regulator so it might not work with 3.3V input? Also why have you put external 10k pull-up resistors if the module already has much stronger 4k7 pull-up resistors to onboard-regulated 3.3V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong pins on the Nucleo.

You have connected to PC8 and PC6, not to PB8 and PB9.

Comment: How did I missed that ! many thanks !!!

Comment: I added the pin-out from the user manual to help future self :-)

Comment: Obviously I don't need the pull-up anymore and the 3.3 is working fine, thanks!